# Ссылка на Placemark в дом дереве

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

подскажите, как можно получить ссылку на Placemark в дом-дереве?
Создал кастомный темплэйт, мне нужно при hover'e добавлять к нему класс active.

```
var MarkTemplate = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<div class="placemark"></div>' ...
```

Comment: тут есть пример смены метки при наведении https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_rollover

Comment: У меня метка задается background'ом в стилях, плюс анимировать ее надо

Comment: Любые манипуляции с метками стоит делать средствами API, навешивать внешние CSS'ы на элементы внутри карты - порочная практика. Вот пример с анимацией: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_layout